# Filter nodes by paragraph user reference

Tags: 8, nodes

Say you have a content type **Exercise** which has a **Related Users** paragraph field. In turn, **Related Users** has a user reference field:

(content type) **exercise** --> (paragraph) **related_users** --> (user) **user**

I want to filter all Exercises with a certain related user:

```
/api/node/exercise?filter[field_related_users.field_user.name]=some_user
```

But it returns empty data: **"data": [],**. Same if tried with user id.

I'm sending a request with admin user, so there are no permission issues. Also, I did a similar filtering on a referenced content type (with a user reference) and it does return data.

I couldn't find anything related to this in JSON:API open issues. Does filtering by paragraph reference work differently? Or maybe there are limitations on this?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am experiencing the same issue when trying to filter by a node reference within a paragraph. No data is being returned...

Comment: @Hubert I didn't find a solution to this, but I did a work around something along lines of adding the users field to the exercises node and keeping it in sync with the users in the related_users paragraph.

So, every time related_users is saved, I'd update the users field in the exercise node as well. I think I then hid this field from displays. It is this node users field that I used for filtering. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that makes sense, I guess I'll have to do something like that too. Seems that it is a JSON:API bug, then. I've opened an issue about it on the Drupal.org site.

Answer (score 0):

According to this issue, [Unable to filter on columns of entity reference fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi/issues/2958587). It seems like you need to add `.entity` after the field name to the entity reference fields.

Try to use this URL instead:

```
/api/node/exercise?filter[field_related_users.entity.field_user.entity.name]=some_user
```

Or if `field_related_users` can contain multiple values, you might want to do like this instead:

```
/api/node/exercise?filter[field_related_users.0.entity.field_user.entity.name]=some_user
```

Comment: That's useful to know, thanks. I tried it, but still empty data is returned. What else do you think could be causing it? Have you ever tried?

Comment: I have tried something similar. Are you sure that the user that’s referenced has the name you filter on?

Comment: Maybe try to filter on .id and check for the entity ID to see if it returns something.

Comment: Did it finally work?

Comment: Both JSON:API request from this answer aren't working for me.

Comment: Could this be the same issue as with https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/3097493?